# What is the best and quickest way to learn Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I am new to Drupal development and I want to learn it quickly.

I think beginners can learn Drupal from drupal.org or by reading some Drupal books but that may take months to start building Drupal sites.

Is there better way of learning Drupal development so that I can start building Drupal sites in couple of weeks rather than months?

Answer (score 1):

For me , i installed drupal and i tested every module and every theme on drupal.org,but if you speak french i recommand you this [website](http://www.drupalfacile.org/) it's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn anything is to use it.  So you should start a project and start working. There are also Drupal meetups and Drupal camps where you can learn from other users.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Drupal developer / trainer and mostly use http://drupalize.me/ to train people. Although it is not free but it is the best way to learn Drupal. You should start with followings to quickly learn and build sites in Drupal,

1. [Site Building with Drupal 7 Series](http://drupalize.me/series/site-building-drupal-7-series)
2. [Intro to Fields for Site Builders Series](http://drupalize.me/series/intro-fields-site-builders-series)
3. [Intro to Views for Drupal 7 Series](http://drupalize.me/series/intro-views-drupal-7-series)

To know about various modules and how do they work, you can look at this site http://codekarate.com/ where new videos are being added on daily basis.